# What chemical species is really acting as oxidizer in hot concentrated sulfuric acid

Tags: acid-base, oxides

In some japanese website it is written that hot conc sulfuric acid has greater oxidation power than that of normal temperature since it contains sulfur trioxide formed by decomposition of the sulfuric acid.
（[like this](https://kinki.chemistry.or.jp/pre/a-317.html#:%7E:text=%E5%B8%B8%E6%B8%A9%E3%81%AE%E6%BF%83%E7%A1%AB%E9%85%B8%E3%81%AF,%E4%BD%9C%E7%94%A8%E3%82%92%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82))
But I couldn't find any source about this theory.
Does anyone know anything about this?

I must say that this is not a duplicate question.
Since I am asking about something different from someone else's previous questions.
What I am concerned is what chemical species is actually involved in the oxidation reaction of hot concentrated sulfuric acid. Not the existence of sulfur trioxide.